# PowerShell Import-CSV and replace - order of operation

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple replace function. It goes through a list of IP addresses and replaces the first 3 octets. It seems that they have to be in a specific order, why?

**Working:**

```
$testips = Import-CSV Test.csv

function change_PROD_IP

{
    $PROD_oldIP = $line.NodeIP
    $PROD_newIP = $line.NodeIP -replace "10.245.0.","10.165.221." `
        -replace "10.245.14.","10.165.233." `
        -replace "10.245.15.","10.165.234." `
        -replace "10.245.12.","10.165.236." `
        -replace "10.245.13.","10.165.237." `
        -replace "10.245.1.","10.165.222." `

    Add-Content -Path Production_Nodes_Test.csv -Value "$PROD_Oldip, $PROD_newIP"
}

foreach ($line in $testips) {change_PROD_ip}
```

But if I take the last line and put this first:

```
-replace "10.245.1.","10.165.222." `
```

Then it starts to use this line for replacing `10.245.12/13/14` i.e. anything that has the third octet beginning with 1. Why is this the case as it is an explicit definition with a "." after the 1?

Comment: While it's not a long list yet, consider building a data structure that has the mapping and use a look to work with it. This might also allow you to arbitrary replaces.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are not aware of the fact that `-replace` is using a *regex* to replace the content and the `.` matches any characters. So you either have to *escape* your dots using a backslash: `\.` or you use the Replace method intead:

```
$line.NodeIP.Replace("10.245.0.","10.165.221.").Replace(.....
```